# Sum of 3 numbers representing Hours in linq query or c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have column with spent hours values like (10.30,1.45 ...)
I want to sum those numbers to get the total spent hours.
Example:

> Values 11.11,
> 0.50, 0.59
>
> Total spent hours 11 and the sum of minutes
> (11 + 50 + 59) = 120 minutes = 2 hour
>
> So my final output should be 11 + 2 = 13.00 hour

but in my c# query I am getting 11.11 + 0.50 + 0.59 = 12.2 which is wrong as i considered it as hour format.

How can get the result 13.00 hours without splitting the numbers.

I Tried:

```
db.myTable.Where(t => t.is_deleted == false).Sum(t => t.time_spent)
```

which is giving me 12.2 but i want 13.00 as i considered it as time.

**EDIT:**

I used

```
List<string> hoursTemp1 = Model.tblName.Where(t => t.is_deleted == false).Select(p => p.time_spent.ToString()).ToList();
    var total_effort_hr = new TimeSpan(hoursTemp1.Sum(x => TimeSpan.ParseExact(x, "h\\.mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Ticks)).ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

But now I am Getting OverflowException for Hour value Greater then 24 and minute value greater then 60

So can anyone please help me how to resolve this error and get proper result?
Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: i guess there is something wrong about units in your values. what is difference 11.11 and 0.50 they are min, sec ?

Comment: Should you not be using the timespan type for this sort of stuff?

Comment: Please specify the ORM you are using and the actual type of the values because the correct answer depends on that.

Comment: @Badiparmagi they are hh.mm format hour.minute...

Comment: @Netferret Your suggession is perfect. I used 'Sloth' Solution of using timespan and its working as i expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        var times = new string[] { "11.11", "0.50", "0.59" };
        var totalTime = new TimeSpan(times.Sum(x => TimeSpan.ParseExact(x, "h\\.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Ticks));
        Console.WriteLine(totalTime); //13:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks. This really helps me out. Perfect solution which i want.

Answer (score 1):

```
public decimal GetHours(IEnumerable<decimal> args)
{
   return args.Sum(x=> Math.Truncate(x) + (x-Math.Truncate(x))*100/60);
}
```

Or with one truncate:

```
public decimal GetHours(IEnumerable<decimal> args)
{
   return args.Sum(x=> (5*x-2*Math.Truncate(x))/3);
}
```

But seriously, I will cutoff hand for such datetime handling. Almost every database has type that represents date, time or both. Why not to use them to avoid this kind of crap?

Comment: Our database has thousands of records with this type of values and now we cant change its datatype everywhere in our application